# Cannot run composer on cmd after installing it

Tags: windows, composer-php

So I've installed composer and it can't be called via cmd. Everytime I run **composer** via cmd command line it will show me like this :

[image]

I forgot what I did to **composer** command but I think it was some **echo** command in **@php**. So any ideas to solve this? Thanks

Comment: I think I use the command from [link](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md) where it says **C:\bin>echo @php "%~dp0composer.phar" %*>composer.bat** and the error happened

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE:

So I uninstalled the composer, removed the left-over directory manually at `C:\Users\<user>\Composer` , `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local` , `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming` , removed composer PATH at Environment Variables, then reinstalled it by running the ComposerSetup.exe from `https://getcomposer.org` , re-adding the composer PATH at Environment Variables (in my case `C:\Users\<user>\composer`) and it works. Composer can be called globally from cmd.

Answer (score 0):

Is it in your PATH? You may need to add it to your PATH in order for it to be "found" and executed when you call `composer` in the command prompt.

Check out the docs here: https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#installation-windows

Comment: there's 3 path already, **C:\Users\<User>\AppData\Local\ComposerSetup\bin** , **C:\Users\<User>\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin** , **C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin** . But still I cant execute composer on cmd

Comment: Thank you for the answer sir

Comment: No problem, glad I could help!